# SpEL: How to check if variable matches any element from list?

Tags: spring-el

In SQL we have construction to check if variable matches any element from list:

```
id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

How to check it with SpEL?
(something as `#id in (1, 2, 3)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpEL is fully based on Java, so whatever you can do with `Collection` is available in SpEL, too.

So, I would implement your request as:

```
{1,2,3}.contains(#id)
```

Having list of desired values as inline definition and assuming that `id` is an evaluation context variable.

More info in Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-language-ref